# Replace the symbol in list

Tags: python, list

my_list=['A0_123','BD_SEI','SW_TH']

I need to replace the '_' to '+' .

Expected output:
my_list=['A0+123','BD+SEI','SW+TH']
Can some one help me?

Comment: Iterate over the list with index and replace what you want.

Comment: `[i.replace('_', '+') for i in my_list]`

Comment: I suggest @python_user post this as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered and better used for future reference.

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus feel free to do so, I did not post this as an answer as this probably a dupe question and I did not feel like finding the dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @python_user, you can iterate through every element in your list using a list comprehension and using `replace()`:

`new_list = [i.replace('_', '+') for i in my_list]`

Returns your expected output

```
['A0+123', 'BD+SEI', 'SW+TH']
```